# Как подключить интернет и не сломать Manifest file

Tags: java, android

знаю опять минусы полетят но уже 4 часа не пойму что делать, подскажите, пытался сделать новое activity что бы выводило на веб версию сайта, нашел код в инете протестировать его как будет работать заодно изучить содержание кода

```
package com.example.magictrans;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class find extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find);

        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        final Activity activity = this;

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://magic-trans.ru/");

        setContentView(webView);
```

в итоге писало что не находит интернет, попробовал вложить в манифест вот такой код

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

в итоге поломался манифест и не работает приложение((( выдает ошибку

AAPT: error: '' is incompatible with attribute fullBackupContent (attr) reference|boolean.

я понимаю что проблема вот тут android:fullBackupContent="", насколько я понял значение должно быть true или false. Ставлю значение в итоге опять эта ошибка((( не понимаю в чем проблема. Уже даже удалил все содержимое и заново взял из стартового проекта( моя ошибка гидхаб не подключен еще), все ровно та же ошибка выходит. Везде в инете советуют изменить значение в ковычках или удалить, но ничего не помогает.

Помогите пожалуйста, может нужно удалить полностью файл манифеста и создать заново его?

PS забыл сам манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.magictrans"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:fullBackupContent=""
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MagicTrans" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.magictrans.find"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_find"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MagicTrans.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.magictrans.fullcalc"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fullcalc"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MagicTrans.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.magictrans.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Если не знаете для чего этот атрибут, то он вам явно не нужен - можете смело убрать его вообще. А на досуге почитать: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

Comment: Если бы я знал как((( я пытаюсь удалить атрибут но он возвращается.
Ставлюandroid:allowBackup="true" тут false и все ровно обратно возвращается.
Решил настроить файл как выше сказано по ссылке для резервного копирования и все ровно он выдает 
AAPT: error: '' is incompatible with attribute fullBackupContent (attr) reference|boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Все вопрос отпал.
Все это время я глупый человек пытался изменить дебаг манифест, надо было просто зайти в обычный файл манифеста в app и удалить резервное копирование, либо там же настроить его.
Короче удалил из основного файла и все заработало спасибо большое за помощь.